# Health check endpoint for AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm new to serverless and AWS so I'm unsure how to have a health check endpoint `/healthcheck` for my actual processing Lambda or if it's even needed at all. I want to be able to check the health even without access to AWS account and without calling the actual Lambda. I'm using just a simple workflow of API Gateway > Lambda > DynamoDB. As far as I understand, it is possible for the service to be down in all 3 stages.

I know of Route 53 but I don't think it fits what I want because it calls the endpoint repeatedly and I think access to AWS account is needed as well.

It is possible to have `/healthcheck` Lambda to just return that the endpoint is up and if service is down, then there would be nothing returned but this does not seem like the correct approach since the endpoint can never return down.

Maybe AWS health API to report public health events would work but it seems like it works in the reverse manner - report when there's an issue instead of having an endpoint to check myself. Is that the recommended method to check health for serverless?

Answer (score 3):

You keep mentioning Lambda as an entire service, so if that is what you mean, then AWS operates a regional health page by service: https://status.aws.amazon.com/

You can also use the Health API https://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/ug/monitoring-logging-health-events.html to return a status of 'healthy' unless it finds a entry for Lambda (or whichever) that indicates unhealthy.

If you are looking instead to deploy a Lambda function that says 'I am alive and can access specific resources I need', then perhaps you should develop a simple function to deploy in `/healthcheck` that has the same permissions as the real function and does some small actions like check and record a dummy value in DynamoDB to make sure it can access it/ read it/ modify it/ delete it or whatever else it is supposed to do there.  It could also return some simple stats on the dynamodb table that are recorded in cloudwatch to indicate the health of the table to you in a more simple manner than searching in the console
(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/metrics-dimensions.html)